# Which comes first, values-sw or values-dpi?

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to know which has the highest priority, **sw** or **dpi**, as you all know I can provide some android resource folders according to both of them, for example there is the `res/value` folder which can be provided according to the device **smallest-width** or device **density** in the form of `res/values-sw600dp` and `res/values-hdpi` respectively, So, if I have a device which will match these two, which value would it take? the one in the **hdpi** or the one in the **sw600dp**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2) lists all of the qualifiers in order of precedence.

The smallest-width qualifier has higher precedence than the screen pixel density qualifier.

You may also be interested in the [How Android finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) documentation.